# Coldfusion find if column has value

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a table which has a column LanguageID. It has seven values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 22

Now I have a function that gets the languageID of the current user.

**I want to check if that languageID exists in my table, if it exists return that value, if not then return default 2. If 2 doesn't exist in that table then return 1.**

This is my query:

```
<cfquery name="NameName" datasource="mydatabase">
        SELECT DISTINCT SomeID,
        SomeName,
        LanguageID
        FROM myDatabase WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE BlacklistReasonID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.BlacklistReasonID#" />
        <cfif isDefined(arguments.LanguageID)> //I want to check if the arguments.LanguageID exists in the table
            AND LanguageID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.LanguageID#" />
        <cfelseif NOT isDefined(arguments.LanguageID) > //ako nema value
            AND LanguageID = 2 //default, put languageID to 2
        <cfelse>
            AND LanguageID = 1 //if languageID 2 doesn't exist in that table, then put 1
        </cfif>
    </cfquery>
```

So real life example. The funtion activates, the LanguageID is 3. That's ok, the first cfif check to see if the table has a value of 3, it has, ok then it puts the languageID to 3 and ends.

Second scenario. The funtion activates, the LanguageID is 44. The first cfif checks to see if the table has a value of 44, it **doesn't have that value**, so the second cfif activates and puts the LanguageID to 2.

Comment: The way your condition is, it will never go in cfelse block. Either arguments.LanguageID exists or it does not. So either it goes to 1st part or 2nd.

Comment: @CFML_Developer I know that. That's why I'm stuck here :(

Comment: If LanguageID has a default value of 2, under what circumstances would it be 1?

Comment: Do you actually mean to check if the table contains a row with `LanguageID = 2` and fall back to a row with `LanguageID = 1` in case it doesn't?

Comment: How many rows are you expecting out of this query?

Comment: FYI Your `isDefined()` check is incorrect. The variable you are checking should be enclosed in quotes: `isDefined("arguments.LanguageID")`

Comment: This would be better handled at the SQL server rather than in ColdFusion. What flavor and version of both are you using?

Comment: And `WITH NOLOCK` probably isn't needed. It's likely not doing what you think it's doing anyway and can cause bad results.  https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in the SQL itself. That would likely be much more performant than having ColdFusion try to do query processing.

I made a couple of assumptions, based on your original question. First, that this query should only return 1 result (`TOP 1`). And second, that your default languages are `2` for `Default1` and `1` for `Default2`. This also includes that the value you are searching for will be greater than 1 or 2.

```
SELECT TOP 1 SomeID, SomeName, LanguageID
FROM (
  SELECT SomeID, SomeName, LanguageID
  FROM t1
  WHERE BlacklistReasonID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.BlacklistReasonID#">
    AND LanguageID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.Language#">

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT SomeID, SomeName, LanguageID
  FROM t1 
  WHERE BlacklistReasonID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.BlacklistReasonID#">
    AND LanguageID IN ( <cfqueryparam value="1,2" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" list="yes"> ) /* DEFAULT IDs */
) s1
ORDER BY id DESC
;
```

This works because a query will return no results if the filtering condition is not matched, but when joined to a query that does have results (your defaults) those will appear in the whole query. Then I order the results and take the top 1.

The basic gist of the query is at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=6f729939d3305e49032eab56d88aa877

I also included several demonstrations of how this works if your `LanguageID` is not found, and one possible way of using default `ID`s that aren't `1` or `2`.

---

And to keep it all in one place:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 ( id int, lang varchar(10) ) ;
> INSERT INTO t1 (id, lang)
> VALUES (1,'Default 2'),(2,'Default 1'),(3,'Klingon')
>   ,(50, 'Common'),(20, 'Nadsat'),(55, 'Furbish')
> ;
> /* If you will only have one language per id, and default IDs will always be 2 and 1 */
> /* Match */
> SELECT TOP 1 id, lang
> FROM (
>   SELECT id, lang 
>   FROM t1
>   WHERE id = 3
>
>   UNION ALL 
>
>   SELECT id, lang
>   FROM t1 
>   WHERE id IN (1,2) /* DEFAULT IDs */
> ) s1
> ORDER BY id DESC
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lang   
> -: | :------
>  3 | Klingon
> ```
>
> ```
> /* No match. */
> SELECT TOP 1 id, lang
> FROM (
>   SELECT id, lang 
>   FROM t1
>   WHERE id = 99999
>
>   UNION ALL 
>
>   SELECT id, lang
>   FROM t1 
>   WHERE id IN (1,2) /* DEFAULT IDs */
> ) s1
> ORDER BY id DESC
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lang     
> -: | :--------
>  2 | Default 1
> ```

> ```
> /* No Default1 Language */
> CREATE TABLE t2 ( id int, lang varchar(10) ) ;
> INSERT INTO t2 (id, lang)
> VALUES (1,'Default 2'),(3,'Klingon')
>   ,(50, 'Common'),(20, 'Nadsat'),(55, 'Furbish')
> ;
>
> SELECT TOP 1 id, lang
> FROM (
>   SELECT id, lang 
>   FROM t2
>   WHERE id = 9999
>
>   UNION ALL 
>
>   SELECT id, lang
>   FROM t2 
>   WHERE id IN (1,2) /* DEFAULT IDs */
> ) s1
> ORDER BY id DESC
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lang     
> -: | :--------
>  1 | Default 2
> ```

> ```
> /* No Default Language */
> CREATE TABLE t3 ( id int, lang varchar(10) ) ;
> INSERT INTO t3 (id, lang)
> VALUES (3,'Klingon')
>   ,(50, 'Common'),(20, 'Nadsat'),(55, 'Furbish')
> ;
>
> /* No match. No Default. */
> SELECT TOP 1 id, lang
> FROM (
>   SELECT id, lang 
>   FROM t3
>   WHERE id = 9999
>
>   UNION ALL 
>
>   SELECT id, lang
>   FROM t3 
>   WHERE id IN (1,2) /* DEFAULT IDs */
> ) s1
> ORDER BY id DESC
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lang
> -: | :---
> ```

> ```
> /* Match, but no default */
> SELECT TOP 1 id, lang
> FROM (
>   SELECT id, lang 
>   FROM t3
>   WHERE id = 3
>
>   UNION ALL 
>
>   SELECT id, lang
>   FROM t3 
>   WHERE id IN (1,2) /* DEFAULT IDs */
> ) s1
> ORDER BY id DESC
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lang   
> -: | :------
>  3 | Klingon
> ```

> ```
> /* Default 1 and 2 are not ID 2 and 1. */
> CREATE TABLE t4 ( id int, lang varchar(10) ) ;
> INSERT INTO t4 (id, lang)
> VALUES (40,'Default 2'),(42,'Default 1'),(3,'Klingon')
>   ,(50, 'Common'),(20, 'Nadsat'),(55, 'Furbish')
> ;
>
> /* No match. Pick Default. */
> SELECT TOP 1 s1.id, s1.lang
> FROM (
>   SELECT id, lang 
>   FROM t4
>   WHERE id = 9999
>
>   UNION ALL 
>
>   SELECT s2.id, s2.lang 
>   FROM (
>     SELECT TOP 1 id, lang
>       , CASE 
>           WHEN ID = 42 THEN 2 
>           WHEN ID = 40 THEN 1 
>           ELSE 0 
>         END AS sortOrder
>     FROM t4 
>     WHERE id IN (40,42) /* NEW DEFAULT IDs */
>     ORDER BY sortOrder DESC
>   ) s2
> ) s1
> ORDER BY s1.id DESC
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lang     
> -: | :--------
> 42 | Default 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=6f729939d3305e49032eab56d88aa877)*

Comment: I also removed `NOLOCK` from the query. See my comment above. blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Qapla'! Exactly what I was going to suggest ;-)

Comment: @Ageax I've already warned you. Being in my head can be a scary place.